# NGINX With Vue 3 Vite SPA - Returning Blank White Page

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nginx, vite

I have the following NGINX config

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root C:/test;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /display/outbound {
            alias C:/test/display/outbound;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /display/outbound/index.html;
        }

        location /display/outbound/api/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:52000/api/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        # Serve .js and .css files with the correct MIME type
        types {
            text/html html;
            application/javascript js;
            text/css css;
        }

        # Serve static assets
        location /assets/ {
            alias C:/test/display/outbound/assets/;
        }

        # Serve favicon
        location /favicon.ico {
            alias C:/test/display/outbound/favicon.ico;
        }
    }
}
```

There are three aspects, the http://localhost route returns a static html page with just a h1 element. This works fine

A Vue 3 Vite SPA, served at http://localhost/display/outbound - From what I can tell, the files are being served correctly, as I can see the contents in the network tab of dev tools. I also have no console errors. However, I am just seeing a blank white page.

When serving the Vue 3 app from http://localhost it works with no issues.

A reverse proxy to my API - This worked fine when hosting my Vue app from http://localhost

Is anybody able to point me in the right direction. I have tried numerous things now, none of which seem to work.

When changing my vite.config.js file and adding

```
base: '/display/outbound/',
```

It serves the app, I can see the pages etc, but the JS breaks and I get the Filter is not a function error. This doesn't happen when serving from http://localhost

I am at a loss on how to proceed. I have tried several variations of my config file, all with the same results. The files are being served, no errors, but blank white page.

Edit - My file structure is as follows

- C:/test - Root directory
- C:/test/index.html - The static html page at
  http://localhost - Can access fine
- C:/test/display/outbound - Contains Vue 3 project with the favicon and index.html, also assets
  subfolder
- C:/test/display/outbound/assets - Contains the Vue 3 JS,
  CSS and other files

Edit 2 - Added pictures of the DOM

[image: DOM1]

[image]

[image: DOM2]

Thanks in advance! If more info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: can you attach a picture of the DOM (from the devtools) of this "blank page"?

Comment: @Yarin_007 Hi Yarin, I have added a couple of pictures to my question, I hope this helps. As you can see, my favicon and index are served fine, because I can see the page title and Vue icon - It just seems to be the JS, CSS etc that i'm having issues with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to resolve this by adding

```
base: '/display/outbound/',
```

to my Vite.config.ts file.

This has now presented me with another issue however, which I have raised at [Vue 3 Vite SPA Served on NGINX at Sub Root Location - Filter is Not a Function Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486384/vue-3-vite-spa-served-on-nginx-at-sub-root-location-filter-is-not-a-function-e)